# Avoiding redundant function calls in Lambda

Tags: java, lambda

I'm trying to parse the contents of a `HTML` style-attribute into a `Map`. This is my code so far. What is bothering me, is the redundant call of the `String::split` method. How could this be optimized?

```
final String style = "padding-left: 6px; font-weight: bold";
final Map<String, String> result = Arrays.stream(style.split(";")) //
              .map(String::trim) //
              .filter(s -> s.split(":").length <= 2) // invalid
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s.split(":")[0].trim(),
                  s -> s.split(":").length > 1 ? s.split(":")[1].trim() : ""));
```

Comment: If that's what you're worried about just add another `.map(s->s.split(":"))` to your stream.  Then the object being observed for the rest of the stream would be the value of `s.split(":")` instead of `s`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put my comment to an answer, instead of constantly calling `s.split(":")`, just make it part of the pipeline like so:

```
 final Map<String, String> result = Arrays.stream(style.split(";")) //
          .map(String::trim)
          .map(s->s.split(":")) //
          .filter(s -> s.length <= 2) //
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0].trim(),
              s -> s.length > 1 ? s[1] : ""));
```

Comment: I'm such a dumbass. It should have been  's.length < 2'. Thanks

Comment: @user871611 If it's s.length < 2, s[1] won't be valid. Perhaps you mean `s.length == 2`

Comment: @Eran: You are right. I updated my question. Changed it to `.filter(s -> s.split(":").length <= 2)` and replaced the `null` for `""` in the `Collectors` since it causes a NPE. Sorry for the fuzz.

Answer (score 5):

You can map the `String` to an array by calling `split` once, and then proceed with processing that array :

```
final Map<String, String> result = Arrays.stream(style.split(";"))
          .map(String::trim)
          .map(s -> s.split(":"))
          .filter(a -> a.length == 2)
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0].trim(), a -> a[1].trim()));
```

I removed the redundant `s -> s.split(":").length > 1` check, since the filter already eliminates arrays that don't have enough elements.

I'm also assuming the filter should require the array to have exactly 2 elements.

Comment: You're assuming the right direction. The filter in my question should have been  `'.filter(s -> s.split(":").length < 2)`.

Comment: @user871611 Actually it should probably be `length == 2`, otherwise the `collect(Collectors.toMap())` step would always produce a `null` value, since `s.split(":").length > 1` would never be true.

Comment: You are right. I updated my question. Changed it to `.filter(s -> s.split(":").length <= 2)` and replaced the `null` for `""` in the `Collectors` since it causes a NPE. Sorry for the fuzz.